# C# with Dll should i import in my project that he can work without instal Excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have a problem, i deployed my application where i have a connection with Excel file but it doesn't work in other laptop. i have that code :

```
{ string constr1 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + m + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
               OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr1);}
```

i wanna just to know witch .dll should i import and includ it in my project that my application connect with Excel file even if Excel is not installed

Comment: Your application cannot connect with Excel if Excel is not installed. You cannot connect with something that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the Microsoft Access Database Engine and your app should work. This link will get you the Access 2010 version (https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255) which should work for OLEDB.12.

If you're looking for support for later versions of Excel be aware that MS has altered the names that they use for this set of libraries.